# Which Scala methods return null instead of an Option and why?

Tags: scala, methods, null, standard-library, scala-option

I wonder if the standard library is completely `null`-free and - if not - would be interested what reasonable use-cases exist where returning `null` is preferable to returning some `Option` instance.

Comment: The only reasonable use case for returning `null` is when you are using a library that expects `null` to be returned from a callback as an indication of "no result." This is often a necessary evil when dealing with legacy Java libraries from Scala code.

Comment: In general, the Scala library methods will either return Option or will throw an exception if called inappropriately (for example, head and last on list). I don't know of any that return null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NamespaceBinding](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/xml/NamespaceBinding.html) returns `null` for the local namespace or in the following case an undefined input.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_24).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> (<foo/>).scope.getURI("something")
res0: String = null
```

Why it's using `String` instead of `Option[URI]`, I don't know.

Comment: Related to `scala.xml.Elem` which takes a `String` prefix value that is expected to be `null` for no namespace prefix. Again, why it's not `Option[String]` is beyond me.

Answer (score 5):

The only place I've seen `null` used in the standard library are optional regex groups.

```
scala> val number = """(\d+)(\.\d+)?""".r // matches digits optionally followed by a . and more digits
number: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\d+)(\.\d+)?
scala> "12" match {
     |   case number(intPart, decimalPart) => (intPart, decimalPart)
     | }
res0: (String, String) = (12,null)
```

I think, the reasoning here is that you don't want to use `Option[String]` for all groups. This would make the code unnecessarily clumsy, if a group is not optional. Unfortunately, it is not known at compile time if a group is optional. So it's either `Option[String]` for all groups or `null` for not matching groups.

Comment: I really like the fact that regex automatically becomes pattern matcher, and the fact that for 90% of the cases you'd want a straight `String`; but since Scala is almost entirely free of weird exceptions, it may have been a good idea if they used `Option[String]` for consistency. `Option[String]` and/or `List` comes up frequently when parsing Json and I don't think I minded them much since I'd use them within for-comprehension.

Comment: @Eugene Tip: if you specify the type, then it won't match against `null`. For example, `case number(intPart: String, decimalPart: String)` won't match the string above.

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of any so I did a google search in the api (inurl:scala-lang.org/api return +null) and it didn't seem to yield any documented use of null.

May be there exist som internal use. The only reasons I can think of for doing that would be to avoid the extra Some-object or to easy integration with java. Both seem unlikely.

Comment: Since Scala doesn't use `return` most of the time, this search wouldn't really catch much.